# Checking employee end date on authorization

Tags: asp.net, .net, authorization

I have an application that the employees of the company I work at use. We use AAD as an identity provider and each user also has an entry in a database with email, start date, end date etc. Now I want to extend our authorization to also check that the employee that is trying to reach an endpoint is currently employed. So basically check that `user.EndDate == null || user.EndDate > DateTime.Now` put simply.

I thought about adding a `EmployeeStillActiveHandler : IAuthorizationHandler`, but the problem is that I need to inject the dbContext to look up the user. In addition it kind of doesn't make sense to use a `IAuthorizationRequirement` because the requirement is not constant, but rather it's always the current time.

So my question is: How can I most easily validate that the logged in user has an `endDate > DateTime.Now`? Preferably by including it in the current authorization pipeline.